# Exception adding scala to maven project

Tags: java, scala, maven

I am trying to create a Java-Scala maven project. I am using intellij 15 and I add scala archetype to maven project. When it tries to generate the pom, it gives error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project visualizer: The desired archetype does not exist (org.scala-tools.archetypes:scala-archetype-simple:1.2) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project visualizer: The desired archetype does not exist (org.scala-tools.archetypes:scala-archetype-simple:1.2)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: The desired archetype does not exist (org.scala-tools.archetypes:scala-archetype-simple:1.2)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.UnknownArchetype: The desired archetype does not exist (org.scala-tools.archetypes:scala-archetype-simple:1.2)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.configureArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:205)
    ... 22 more
```

Here is my pom,

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>application</groupId>
<artifactId>visualizer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </project>
```

I have added scala archetype while creating maven project.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a full pom.xml skeleton for a hybrid Java/Scala project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.yourcompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>yourartifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>yourname</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
          <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
      </plugin>
            <plugin>
          <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.15.2</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>compile</goal>
                      <goal>testCompile</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-RC2</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/reports</reportsDirectory>
          <junitxml>.</junitxml>
          <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-test</id>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked on my personal laptop. Now I just need to the same steps in my official project. By the way, if I have to specify java and scala source folders, how do I do that in a single maven execution xml?

Comment: You do not need to specify if you use the default directory tree.

Comment: If I use artifactId scala-compiler:2.11.8, what all do I need to change?

Comment: I am trying to run this pom file without all the scala test artifacts, but it gives error for scala library 2.11.4. I will try to add the dependency manually and see how far it goes.

Comment: The experiment failed. I manually added the following dependencies:       scala-library-2.11.4.jar
scala-library-2.11.4.pom

scala-compiler-2.11.4.jar
scala-compiler-2.11.4.pom

scala-reflect-2.11.4.jar
scala-reflect-2.11.4.pom   commons-exec-1.0.1.jar
commons-exec-1.0.1.pom

snakeyaml-1.4.jar
snakeyaml-1.4.pom

jackson-core-asl-1.6.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.6.1.pom

jackson-mapper-asl-1.6.1.pom
jackson-mapper-asl-1.6.1.jar       but it looks like a nested dependency that keeps going to previous versions.

Comment: I have successfully built the project. Had to add the dependencies manually, but it works. Will work on getting the dependencies imported in maven repo.